# What is the correct way to reference more than 1 source?

Tags: reference

Please keep in mind that this is for a commercial project and must be legally sound.

When referencing through a footnote (e.g. a little '1' in superscript), what is the correct way to reference in this scenario?

There is 3 references which are all supporting the one statement, in the one position. Here's an imagine of the 3 possible combinations I thought may be the correct way to assist in explaining what I mean:

[image: Example]

Notice that the 3 references are always only 'referring' to the one place in the text.

Please tell me if I've left out any information which may help you to answer. First time posting in this community.

Comment: Apologies in advance for the ambiguity of my explanation. Hopefully the image explains it.

Comment: If it "must be legally sound" you should ask a lawyer, not strangers on the internet.

Comment: What style are you using? According to [Taylor & Francis Group](http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/style/reference/tf_L.pdf) (p. 3), Chicago style does not recommend using more than one note. Instead, a single note can refer to several citations. The citations are separated by semicolons. I don't have access to the Chicago Manual of Style, so someone else may be able to find more specifics.

Comment: Kevin, great advise. Thank you. 

Thank you vanderpn. Unfortunately I'm unaware of the significance/meaning of that group and 'chicago style'. I'll try researching it however please comment with more information if you have the ability to.

Comment: Citations are a matter of style; the Online Writing Lab at Purdue University offers a [guide to the most common citation styles](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/949/1/). The Chicago Manual of Style is the most common style guide for non-journalistic writing in the United States; most journalistic organizations use the Associated Press Stylebook or a derivative of it. We have a [list of common style manuals](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052) if your organization has not adopted one yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because citation questions are off-topic here. You might like to visit the [writers.se] site.

Comment: Thanks curiousdannii for the reference. I'll try that site for similar questions in the future. Let me know if I can opt to close this myself or if I need to wait for an admin.